# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to train a model with  input dim 2499

```
layers = [2499, 689, 363, 192]
activation = ["relu", "relu", "sigmoid"]
# let's build our model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
# we add the first layer and the input layer to our network
model.add(Dense(layers[1], input_shape=(layers[0],), activation=actv[0]))
# we add the hidden layers
for (x, i) in enumerate(layers):
    if x > 1 and x != (len(layers) - 1):
        model.add(Dense(i, activation=actv[x]))
        # then add the final layer
        model.add(Dense(layers[-1], activation=actv[-1]))
```

When I give input of (72,2499) gives an error of :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2499 but received input with shape (None, 28)
```

I do not understand why am I getting this error as the last dimension of the array(72,2499) is the same as the input shape 2499?

Comment: Your data's input shape is `(Batch_size, 28)` whereas you want it to be `2499`. The argument `input_shape` is based on the data.

Comment: @yudhiesh that is what I am surprised of. The input array shape should be of (x , input_shape) is it not? So if I am providing an array of (72 , 2499)  why is it not working? what am I missing here?

Comment: Your input seems to be (None,28), not (72,2499). I suggest that you check your input for instance with your_dataset.element_spec: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#dataset_structure

Comment: Your input is obviously not shaped (72, 2499), else you wouldn't be getting this error. This is why you should provide a _complete_ example in your question, i.e. one that includes all relevant code and variables. We have no idea what your input looks like because it's not in your question.

Comment: I found the problem I made a stupid error of feeding the trainY rather trainX as input. Thanks for everyone's effort

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Issue was resolved after feeding right data (i.e trainX) to the model
> working as expected (paraphrased from Bigyan Subedi)